# Is it possible to communicate to other WiFi users in the house?

Tags: wireless-networking

I was wondering if it is possible for me to communicate to other WiFi users?

At my flat, there are about 12 people using WiFi from the same modem and, sometimes, they seem to use it too much all at once.
So I wanted to be able communicate straight to each one of them and tell them to slow down on streaming videos online and stuffs.

Comment: I miss netsend :-(

Comment: Why not monitor the usage at the modem and identify which computer is using too much and go bug that person.

Comment: Oh I can do that? How do monitor to see which uses too much?

Comment: Just a quick non IT point, if you don't manage the broadband for the house and start sending them messages telling them to use less they might not take to kindly to it. I'd certainally not be less than happy if someone started popping messages up on my screen telling me to download less.

Comment: The easiest way to communicate in this circumstance is to shout "Who's downloading stuff? You're using up all the bandwidth." Or figure out who it is and then walk over to them. Don't overcomplicate things.

Comment: Are you providing the internet service?  Or do you just share it with everyone else?  What is the *reason* for this post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way that I can see is using a computer behind the Wifi-router configured as proxy of your network.

Besides the fact that your network sharers will need to log-in onto the proxy to enable network access, you can create a "broadcasting" message blocking traffic for some time and spreading a specific web pop-up that will broadcast any message that you want for all your users. I never did such thing but I think using a proxy is the best scenario for you if you are sharing your network bandswitch over Wi-fi.

Comment: Yes i realized about this proxy thing too but I'm just one of the wifi users in my flat, so i can't really set up a computer to run all day long behind the wifi modem. All i can do is to use wifi and access to the wifi modem. Is there any other way i could do without using proxy thing?

Comment: Hmmm, I thought you were the owner of the network access, downright I hope I'm wrong, but I don't think you have any options except talk with internet owner and explain him the high trafic situation. He could implement a sharing policy for the users.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, just because you use the same WiFi access point, it doesn't mean you'll be able to communicate with them.

Your ability to communicate with them is largely dependent on what operating system the other users use and what communication tools they have installed/available.

Comment: I know what they use, mac and windows. I was pretty sure i had heard it before, something about people can communicate with other wifi users from the same wifi modem without having to install any software. Since computer security nowadays are tight, it makes me wonder. Is there anyway at all that could be done?

Comment: People generally don't like it if weird messages pop out on their screen out of nowhere. There simply is no way to force a user to see a given message without prior agreeing on a given communication platform. You all need to install Skype or message each other via Facebook or something like that. There simply is no default, built-in approach to this.

Comment: Yes that could be one the reasons why I want to be able to send a message to them to be considerate of others usage.

Answer (score 0):

because you are using same router, you are in the same network . then you can ping others and connect to them and communicate . i think one of the softwares was used to communicate was `Net Send Messenger`
nowadays must be other better softwares

Comment: do other computers have to install this software too?

Comment: @James1 "*Send Messages to Any Windows XP / NT / 2000 Computer without requiring a server installed on the remote machine.*" Forget that crap, seriously. `net send` is long dead and gone.

Comment: @james1 i think so , but i didn't used it

Answer (score -1):

You need to enable QoS provisions of that modem. in perfect case that would do a fair queuing with everybody getting equal dose of 'net

Comment: How do i enable the quality of service? I have just googled and not too sure what it is yet.

Comment: @James1: QOS ensures that the quality of the service is kept at a certain level. you can decide on what that level is (aka "the policy"). eg, if 10 folks want to max out video-streams while the max available bandwidth is just X, you can either give each user X/10 or any other share of whats available. you could also just increase the priority of "important" packtes (like "ACK") and let the users fight themselves with their concurrent downlods.